# overloading operator== comparison 2 class

Tags: c++, overloading, comparison-operators

i'm new in programming and i'm trying to search an element in a list of class and i did this:

```
string x;
cin >> x;
list<Person>::iterator findIter = std::find(ListPerson.begin(), ListPerson.end(), x);
```

but it seem like i must overload the operator== to work, i did this:

```
friend bool operator== (Person &P1, Person &P2);

bool operator== (Person& P1, Person& P2)
{
    return (P1.Name == P2.Name);
}
```

but it doesn't work i got always this error : c2678 binary '==' no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type Person.
Thank you for helping !

Comment: What is the type of `x`? Whatever it is, you need to have a == operator that takes a `Person` as lhs, and type of `x` as rhs

Comment: ah sorry it's a string, thank you very much :D it seems like it works

Answer (score 0):

Your `friend bool operator==` declaration should be inside the class declaration. Next, pass by `const` reference instead, as rvalues cannot bind to non-`const` references and also the [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) expects its compared-to element by `const` reference. So your `operator==` should be able to compare `const` references, and non-`const` ones will not do since they will discard const qualifiers. To fix, declare

```
friend bool operator==(const Person &P1, const Person &P2);
```

Live working example [here](http://ideone.com/wNn4RI).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring the parameters as constant references? A comparison operator does not need to have side-effects.

The following works for me, and prints `yeah`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct P {
    const int x;

    P(int x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
};

bool operator== (const P & p1, const P &p2) {
    return p1.x == p2.x;
}

int main()
{
    P x(0), y(0), z(1);

    if (x == y) {
        cout << "yeah" << endl;
    }
    if (y == z) {
        cout << "nope" << endl;
    }
}
```

Of course you might need to declare the `operator==` as a friend function if you want to do a comparison over private instance variables.

```
class P {
    int x;

  public:
    P(int x) {
        this->x = x;
    }

    friend bool operator== (const P &p1, const P &p2);
};
```

Comment: Which change? The const reference or the friend function? Also please elaborate on why it doesn't work. Error messages?